# Simple html table design issue

Tags: html, html-table

I'm trying to solve a problem: it's a HTML exercise in which I must write the HTML code for a table with this design:

[image: the design of the wanted table]

But I can't seem to set it straight, here's my code:

```
    <table border>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2" colspan="2"> Batatas </td>
            <td rowspan="3" colspan="2"> Couves </td>
            <td> Alhos </td>
            <td> Cebolas </td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
            <td rowspan="2" colspan="2"> Alface </td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
            <td colspan="2"> Nabos </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
```

And here's the result:

[image]

Shouldn't the rowspan="2" in the first "td" tag make the first cell larger (in height)?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Stumped me too! [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZkvL2/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this online tool here: http://html-tables.com/

and you will see how the 3 rows collapse to 2 rows visually if you are using just cell merging.

I think you need to nest tables to achieve that effect.

Comment: I don't think tables should be used in this case. Is it semantically correct to use tables?

Answer (score 1):

Actually the problem you are facing is not because of your code it is because of general rules of html table rendering, this arises because of merging of table cells

To resolve this drawback of `<table>` tag, I'll recommend to use `<div>` tag as better approach.
Try this....

```
  <table border>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2" colspan="1"> Batatas </td>
            <td rowspan="3" colspan="1"> Couves </td>
            <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"> Alhos </td>
            <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"> Cebolas </td>
        </tr>

        <tr> 
            <td rowspan="1" colspan="2"> Alface </td>
        </tr>

        <tr rowspan="1" colspan="2"> 
            <td> Nabos </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
```

---

### Update

As I've noticed, this can't be done using `<table>` tag, You can use the `div` approach. These `div` tag are able to generate your layout.

I just finished working on your problem, and I've just solved your problem using `<div>` tag, Have a look

```
<div style=" background-color: powderblue;border:1px solid black; width:410px; height:310px">
<div style="float:left;">
    <div style="border:1px solid black; width:100px; float:none; height:200px">Batatas
    </div>
    <div style="border:1px solid black; width:100px; float:none; height:99px">Nabos
    </div>
</div>
<div>   
    <div style="border:1px solid black;width:100px; float:left; height:301px">Couves
    </div>
    <div style="border:1px solid black;width:100px; float:left; height:100px">Alhos
    </div>
    <div style="border:1px solid black;width:100px; float:left; height:100px">Cebolas
    </div>
    <div style="border:1px solid black;width:202px; float:left; height:199px">Alface
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @ArthurFrankel  Yes, I know but this partially fulfills your request, please read the reason which I just posted in my answer, why it can't be done

Comment: agreed - it really depends on the true usage of the html table.  Yours maybe correct as well as my answer. If not one of these, then certainly switching to divs/css is much better.

Comment: Yes.. that would be a final option

Comment: Thanks for your effort, it visually gives what I asked. However, I intended to use only tables, and asked to see if it was possible to achieve it that way

Comment: Yes, You're welcome... I can understand your problem, because this is an exercise, anyway It was a good question, and I'd also like to know the solution for this problem, thus making it my favorite, Thanks for asking such a good question.

Answer (score 0):

Good question.  The closest I got (without getting crazy with nested tables) is simply this:

```
  <table border>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"> Batatas </td>
        <td rowspan="3" colspan="2"> Couves </td>
        <td> Alhos </td>
        <td> Cebolas </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
        <td rowspan="2" colspan="2"> Alface </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"> Nabos </td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

[image]

If this doesn't work for you (and you don't want to get into complex nested html tables), then I the common belief seems to be to move away from html tables to using CSS. Obviously with CSS/divs you have much more control.

Comment: Why did someone give me a negative here?  One of the other answers doesn't even work and I'm offering a solution that may be ok - since we don't know the full use here.  The obvious answer is to use div/CSS.